# How can I get column number using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

```
Select columnnuber
from tablename
where condition
```

Is there any way to get column number. I am retrieving data from cav file using csv jdbc driver.

Comment: Please explain what *you* mean by "column number".

Comment: Did you check the [ResultSet interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#findColumn(java.lang.String)) docs? No any DB specific metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the position of a column in a table when you do `select *` -- which is basically the position when the table is created -- then you can look in the `information_schema` tables.

```
select ordinal_position
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = ? and column_name = ?;
```

You may need to include the `table_schema` as well.